# My website does not show the color of the icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making a website where, I have added social media icons but they are not visible on the screen. I have added color of all the icons in my CSS file. it does not show the headings of those icons too. I am new to web development, so do bear with me.
Below is my HTML code:

```css
.h1 {
  font-size: '150%';
  color: 'beige';
}

.h3 {
  color: 'beige';
}

.contact-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.contact-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  background-color: black;
  height: 600 px;
  padding: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social-buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2 px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 15px;
}

.blue-circle2 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 89, 255);
}

.red-circle1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.pink-circle1 {
  background-color: rgb(251, 57, 88);
}

.blue-circle3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Home page</title>
  <link rel="style" href="CSS/style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div className="container">
    <div className="contact-header">
      <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    </div>
    <div className="contact-content">

      <h3>Reach out to us at <a className="email-link" href="ourlibrary@gmail.com">email</a></h3>

    </div>
    <div className="social-buttons">
      <!--- <a href=>--->
      <div className="red-circle1">
        <img src="./img/youtube.svg" alt="YouTube icon" width='40' height='40' />
      </div>
      </a>
      <!--- <a href="https://twitter.com/CampusAndroid">---->
      <div className="blue-circle2">
        <img src="./img/twitter.svg" alt="Twitter icon" width='40' height='40' />
      </div>
      </a>
      <!--- <a href=>--->
      <div className="blue-circle3">
        <img src="./img/facebook.svg" alt="Facebook icon" width='40' height='40' />
      </div>
      </a>
      <!--- <a href=>--->
      <div className="pink-circle1">
        <img src="./img/instagram.svg" alt="Instagram icon" width='40' height='40' />
      </div>
      </a>
      <!--- <a href=>--->
      <div className="blue-circle2">
        <img src="./img/linkedin.svg" alt="LinkedIn icon" width='40' height='40' />
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is what my website looks like:
[image]

Where am I going wrong? Please suggest.

Comment: Did you mean `class` instead of `className`?

Comment: `className` is used in `React.js` to remove the clash with `class` in `JavaScript`. It seems like it is normal `html/css` based website. As @SebastianSimon said, replace `className` with `class` then your `css` will be applied. :)

Comment: i changed it but it still shows the same thing :(

Comment: guys it worked when i changed the images from .svg to .png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in `Html` we use `class` not `className`. We use `className` in [React.js](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html), `JSX`. If you are interested, I recommend reading ;-)
But to the point. You can use [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use) to enjoy the icons on your site. They are very easy to use and really cool.To link them you can use [cdn](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome) or other methods(read docs). Below simple example with snippets of your code. I hope You enjoy it. Good Luck ;-)

```css
.h1 {
  font-size: "150%";
  color: "beige";
}
.h3 {
  color: "beige";
}
.contact-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.contact-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 600 px;
  padding: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social-buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2 px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 15px;
}

.fa-youtube {
  background-color: white; /*background-color of your icon*/
  color: red; /*color of your icon*/
  font-size: 3rem; /*size of your icon*/
}

.fa-font-awesome{
  color: red; 
  font-size: 3rem; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover"
    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <title>FontAwesome Icons</title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="contact-header">
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="contact-content">
        <h3>
          Reach out to us at
          <a class="email-link" href="ourlibrary@gmail.com">email</a>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="social-buttons">
        <div className="red-circle1">
          <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
        </div>
        <div className="red-circle2">
          <i class="fab fa-font-awesome"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Khushi You're welcome ! Glad I could help You ;-)